# Quelles parties du monde francophone continuent à utiliser les nombres réformés pour dénombrer au-delà de 69?

Tags: usage, nombres, régionalismes

Il existe en français des mots pour exprimer les multiples de dix, pour les valeurs au-delà de 60 : septante (70), huitante/octante (80), et nonante (90).  Ils ne sont pas utilisés en France.  Quelles parties du monde francophone continuent à utiliser ces mots, et est-ce qu'ils deviennent de plus en plus utilisés, ou pas ?

Aussi, existe-il des mots semblables pour exprimer les nombres 17, 18, et 19 plus naturellement que dix-sept, dix-huit, et dix-neuf ?

Enfin, pourquoi la France n'utilise-t-elle pas ces mots ? La langue française semble être presque la seule à ne pas avoir des mots qui continuent naturellement après 69.

Comment: "*Ils ne sont pas utilisés en France*" -> Ils le sont, mais très peu (notamment par les personnes âgées dans certaines régions).

Comment: "Presque la seule", mais pas la seule, d'après https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syst%C3%A8me_vic%C3%A9simal qui a d'autres informations sur le sujet. Le système danois notamment a été accusé d'être trop difficile à comprendre pour les enfants (par exemple le nom pour "90" n'est pas le raccourci de "quatre fois vingt plus dix", mais de "un demi avant 5, fois vingt", soit 4½ fois vingt)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[Wikipedia résume la situation actuelle](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nombres_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Variantes_des_adjectifs) et a des articles plus détaillés sur les manières d'épeler [70](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/70_%28nombre%29#Linguistique), [80](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/80_%28nombre%29#Linguistique) et [90](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/90_%28nombre%29#Linguistique). [Historiquement](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/989/dou-vienent-soixante-dix-et-quatre-vingt-plutot-que-septante-et-huitante), il y a eu des va-et-vient.

Les Romains comptaient par dizaines, mais les Celtes et les Normands par vingtaines. Au Moyen Âge, en France, le système vicésimal (compte par 20) est plus utilisé que le système décimal (par 10) ; on disait plutôt « *vint et dis* » (30), « *deux vins* » (40), « *trois vins* » (60), etc. À la fin du Moyen Âge (peut être sous influence italienne, mais c'est une conjecture), les formes décimales sont devenues dominantes : trente, quarante, soixante, … Pour 80, il y a deux formes : *[huitante](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/huitante)*, dérivée du latin populaire, et *[octante](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/octante)*, dérivation savante du XVIII<sup>e</sup> siècle. Quant au curieux hybride *[soixante-dix](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/soixante-dix)*, il existait déjà en ancien français (attestée au XII<sup>e</sup> siècle).

Les nouvelles formes ont pris inégalement suivant les nombres. Le [dictionnaire de l'Académie française](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionnaire_de_l%E2%80%99Acad%C3%A9mie_fran%C3%A7aise) de 1694 indique (citations partielles) :

> - Septante. Nombre composé de sept dixaines. Il n'a guere d'usage que dans les supputations d'Arithmetique. [T.2 p.467]
> - Huitante ou plutost octante. Nombre contenant huit fois dix. Il n'est point en usage dans le discours commun, on dit, *Quatre-vingts*, mais on s'en sert dans les supputations d'Arithmetique. [T.1 p.574]
> - Octante. Quatre-vingt. Il n'a guere d'usage que dans les supputations d'Arithmetique. [T.1 p.574]
> - Nonante. Nombre composé de neuf dixaines. On se sert de ce terme dans l'Arithmetique ; mais dans le discours ordinaire on dit Quatre-vingt-dix. [T.1 p.117]

Au passage, le Dictionnaire épelle 70 « soixante & dix ». Les éditions suivantes considèrent « septante », « octante » et « nonante » comme vieillis. [Littré](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littr%C3%A9), vers 1870, déclare (citations partielles) :

> - [Septante](http://artflx.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/dicos/pubdico1look.pl?strippedhw=septante) : soixante et dix (il a vieilli). Septante, quoique bien préférable à soixante-dix, puisqu'il est dans l'analogie de quarante, cinquante, soixante, n'est guère usité que par des personnes appartenant au midi de la France. Il serait à désirer qu'il revînt dans l'usage et chassât soixante-dix.
> - [Huitante](http://artflx.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/dicos/pubdico1look.pl?strippedhw=huitante) : Quatre-vingts.
> - [Octante](http://artflx.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/dicos/pubdico1look.pl?strippedhw=octante) : Quatre-vingts. Terme vieilli, et c'est dommage, dans la langue littéraire ; il est resté en usage dans le parler du Midi.
> - [Nonante](http://artflx.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/dicos/pubdico1look.pl?strippedhw=nonante) : Nom de nombre cardinal composé de neuf dizaines. Nonante a vieilli, et c'est dommage ; il est resté très usité en Suisse, en Savoie et dans le midi de la France.

De nos jours, dans l'essentiel de la **France** et au **Québec**, on dit « soixante-dix », « quatre-vingts », « quatre-vingt-dix ». Je pense que les formes décimales ne seraient pas comprises par tous les Français.

En **Belgique** et au Luxembourg, on dit « septante », « quatre-vingts », « nonante » ; la frontière linguistique est très proche de la frontière politique, je ne sais pas si elle la recouvre exactement. « Septante » et « nonante » sont aussi utilisés dans les pays africains qui ont été colonisés par la Belgique (RDC, Rwanda et Burundi).

En **Suisse**, et dans quelques petites régions près de la frontière suisse, on dit « septante » et « nonante ». Pour 80, c'est plus compliqué. « Octante » était très employé en Suisse romande encore au XIXe siècle mais est aujourd'hui devenu rare. De nos jours, on dit plutôt « quatre-vingts » dans les cantons proches de la frontière française (Genève, Neuchâtel, Jura) et « huitante » ailleurs.

Il y a quelques noms propres dans lesquels une forme obsolète a été figée, par exemple la [Bible des Septante](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septante) et l'[Hôpital des Quinze-Vingts](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B4pital_des_Quinze-Vingts).

Comment: « Je pense que les formes décimales ne seraient pas comprises par tous les Français. », je confirme, plus d'une fois j'ai dû traduire avant que je ne prenne l'habitude d'utiliser « soixante-dix » et « quatre-vingt-dix ».

Comment: Le mathématicien Italien [Leonardo Fibonacci](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonardo_Fibonacci) a introduit les chiffres arabiques avec le calcul décimal en Europe au 13e siècle. Avec le commerce, la notation romaine a été rapidement supplantée.

Comment: Dit-on « j'ai octante ans » ou « j'ai octante années » ? (de même pour septante, huitante, nonante).

Comment: @Axioplase En France, on dit « j'ai quatre-vingts ans ». Il est possible que « j'ai octante années » ou « j'ai quatre-vingts années » survive comme helvétisme ou régionalisme (pour moi, ça sonne très vieilli, c'est parfaitement compréhensible mais pas idiomatique). C'est peut-être une question à poser sur le site.

Comment: "J'ai huitante ans", tout comme on dit "J'ai soixante ans" ;)

Answer (score 16):

**Septante** : En Suisse, au Val d'Aoste, en Belgique, dans certains pays d'Afrique : au Zaïre et au Rwanda issus de la colonisation Belge et dans certaines régions françaises (Franche-Comté chez les frontaliers Franco-Suisses)

**Huitante** : on le trouve localement en Suisse, dans les cantons de Vaud, Valais, Fribourg et dans le Val d'Aoste.

**Nonante** : en Suisse et en Belgique, au Zaïre et au Rwanda et chez nos amis frontaliers de Franche-Comté.

Pour ce qui est de **octante** il semblerait que cela soit encore utilisé de manière marginale en Suisse romande.

Comment: En Suisse, "huitante" est compris partout, même s'il n'est pas utilisé par tout le monde. Un Genevois ne va pas froncer les sourcils s'il entend "huitante".

Answer (score 7):

La Belgique utilise septante et nonante, mais rarement octante. Les quelques amis que j'ai en Belgique les utilisent systématiquement (note: septante, nonante).

Il m'est arrivé de rencontrer ces deux mots au Luxembourg quelques fois aussi.

Et contrairement à ce que beaucoup pensent en France, nous n'utilisons pas septante et nonante en Moselle :P

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu "octante" utilisé en Belgique.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu septante au Luxembourg. J'y ai entendu nonante par des wallons par contre.

Answer (score 5):

Permettez-moi d'apporter ma petite pierre à l'édifice de ce débat en tant que Belge car je lis beaucoup d'approximations à ce sujet... En Belgique, nous sommes 4,5 millions de francophones en Wallonie et à Bruxelles et nous utilisons tous systématiquement "septante" et "nonante". TOUJOURS ! Par contre, nous utilisons TOUJOURS "quatre-vingts"... C'est l'usage... et c'est regrettable à mon avis car c'est absolumentpas logique... Je ne comprends pas pourquoi... Je n'ai aucune explication. Nous devrions utiliser "octante" mais ce mot n'existe pas en français de Belgique...

Answer (score 4):

La France parisienne n'a définitivement imposé sa manière de compter dans ses écoles françaises que vers le milieu du 20e siècle (Une amie, âgée maintenant de trois vint et huit ans, se souvient qu'en classe, dans l'Ain, septante, octante et nonante étaient de mise!).

Or, cette manière de compter n'est pas « française », mais celte... La défaite de Vercingétorix est-elle donc si dure à admettre, pour refuser d'admettre que le français est une langue LATINE ?

Par contre, que les québécois s'amusent à compter en celte... ça me dépasse !
Un peu plus de logique ferait du bien à tout le monde... Non ?