# Quatre-vingt, octante, huitante… ans ou années ?

Tags: nombres, régionalismes, usage

Comme nous le savons maintenant tous (cf. [ci](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/187/quelles-parties-du-monde-francophone-continuent-a-utiliser-les-nombres-reformes-p) et [ça](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/187/quelles-parties-du-monde-francophone-continuent-a-utiliser-les-nombres-reformes-p)), il existe plusieurs manières de lire les chiffres 70, 80 et 90 selon le dialecte du français qui est utilisé.  Si, hors contexte, l'utilisation de « quatre-vingts » ne me parait pas moins naturelle que celles d'« octante » ou d'« huitante, » j'avoue me demander comment l'on prononce son âge.

J'ai quasiment toujours entendu « quatre-vingts ans » avec une belle liaison et m'y suis habitué. Mais que dit-on dans les régions où « quatre-vingt » n'a pas cours ? « Huitante ans » et « octante ans » sonnent maladroits (à cause de l'allitération), mais « huitante années » ou « septante années » me paraissent peu naturels car je suis habitué à « soixante ans. »

Alors, comment prononce-t-on son âge dans les divers dialectes quand il s'écrit avec les nombres 70, 80 ou 90 ?

Comment: Remarque : "(cf. ci et ça)" ne marche pas, "ci" étant toujours utiliser en conjonction avec un autre mot (celui-ci, ci-devant, etc). Utiliser plutôt "ici et là", ou "ceci et cela" .

Comment: Dans le doute, parler de _80 printemps_. :-)

Comment: @JulienGuertault Oui, ou 80 *berges* éventuellement, en fonction du contexte.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Je fais le choix entre *ans* et *années* après septante et nonante (mon dialecte n'utilise pas *huitante* ou *octante*) exactement suivant les mêmes critères qu'après *soixante*.

Et je prononce *septant'ans*, *nonant'ans* tout comme je prononce *soixant'ans*.

Voir Brel, les Flamandes

> Si elles dansent c'est qu'elles ont septante ans
>   Qu'à septante ans il est bon de montrer

Comment: N'ayant jamais vraiment entendu utiliser ce dialecte, ce n'est qu'un avis, mais l'argument ici me semble pertinent.

Comment: +1 pour la référence lyrique du plat pays!

Answer (score 15):

En français de France (et probablement de quelques autres pays aussi), l'usage veut que l'on emploie "an" lorsqu'il s'agit d'un total (par ex. précédé par "il y a X ans" ou "dans X ans") et "année" lorsque l'on  s'intéresse au "contenu" de la période en question ("durant cette année", "pendant l'année", "au cours de l'année" etc.). Par conséquent, il est plus rare d'entendre "années" au pluriel (mais tout à fait possible: "années 80", par exemple).

Cette règle posée, il est clair qu'il existe de nombreux cas où les deux formes peuvent être employées, avec une nuance plus ou moins divergente:

> Il y a trois années.

... insiste sur la durée (et ce qui a été fait durant ces années), là où:

> Il y a trois ans.

... est plus neutre et donne simplement un positionnement temporel.

À la lumière de ces règles d'usage, je pense que dire "80 années" paraîtrait sinon incorrect, au moins inhabituel: en général, lorsque l'on donne son âge, il s'agit d'une donnée factuelle. L'utilisation du mot "années" insisterait (ici: lourdement) sur l'écoulement de ces années: "J'ai 80 *longues* années".

NB: la règle est la même pour "an"/"année" et pour "jour"/"journée".

Comment: Donc « j'ai "huitantans" » et « elle a "septentans" » se diraient ? Le « tantant » sonne vraiment drôlement…

Comment: Comme le fait remarquer @unFrancophone ci-dessous: pas plus étrange que "soixantans"...

Comment: en fait, la question (sans doute mal posée) concernait le choix d'"an" ou "années" après 70, 80 et 90, selon leur prononciation ; le gros de ta réponse me parait donc HS, désolé :)

Comment: Je comprends bien la question, mais la règle s'applique, quelque soit le contexte: "an" et "année" ne sont pas interchangeables (ni leur usage dicté par l'euphonie).

Comment: @Axioplase, et comme le dit unfrancophone, et le repète ici Dave, si tu sais répondre pour soixante, il n'y a pas vraiment de question à se poser pour septante, huitante et nonante.

Comment: @Benjol : L'allitération me paraissait vraiment bizarre.  Une alternative aurait-été envisageable, d'où ma question.

Answer (score 4):

Il semble que l'on dise

> J'ai septante ans

Information qui semble être corroborée par le Google ngram :

[image: ngram]

Answer (score 4):

En Suisse, on dit "j'ai septante/huitante/nonante ans" et ça sonne tout à fait bien ;) Je n'ai jamais entendu quelqu'un dire "j'ai huitante années"... On dira par contre "les années septante".

A noter que si "septante" et "nonante" font l'unanimité, "huitante" est compris partout sans forcément être utilisé par tout le monde. Dans certains cantons, "quatre-vingts" est plus utilisé (jusqu'à 89, ensuite "nonante") et c'est souvent la formule choisie par les médias. Certaines personnes utilisent aussi "quatre-vingts" pour 80 mais ensuite "huitante-et-un", "huitante-deux", etc.

Answer (score 1):

Septante, huitante et nonante ne sont pas des expressions propre à un dialecte mais au français. Si vraiment on veut pinailler, ce serait plutôt le français de Paris avec ces soixante-dix, quatre-vingts et quatre-vingt-dix qui serait un dialecte.

Comment: Ça n'est pas la question.