# Is it possible to say "soixante-vingt" instead of "quatre-vingt" ? What would be the reaction of native speakers?

Tags: sens, nombres, dialectes

Considering the French say *"soixante-dix"* for *"seventy"*, how possible is it to say "*soixante-vingt*" for "*eighty*" and "*soixante-trente*" for "*ninety*" as the logic behind is the same. You will most probably mention about conventions but:

1. Is it ever used that way by any French speaking society/person?
2. Would a francophone understand what I mean by "*soixante-vingt*" ?
3. What would be their reaction if I ever say "*soixante-vingt*" or "*soixante-trente*" ?
4. How about "*trois-vingt-dix*" ?

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but I'm at the point where constructions like "quatre-vingt-douze" no longer seem like arithmetic exercises and just seem to me like the natural way of saying "92". So I would say that your suggestions would be no more natural to a French speaker than saying "twoteen" or "ten-two" (instead of "twelve") would be to an English speaker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Is it ever used that way by any French speaking society/person?*

No contemporary usage but *soixante-vingt(s)* would likely have been understood to mean 1200 (i.e. 60 x 20) in the Middle-Ages and the next few centuries, when the [vigesimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigesimal) system was still customary.

*Would a francophone understand what I mean by "soixante-vingt" ?*

No, unless perhaps you recite numbers: *soixante-dix-huit, soixante-dix-neuf, soixante-vingt...*

*What would be their reaction if I ever say "soixante-vingt" or "soixante-trente" ?*

A good laugh.

*How about "trois-vingt-dix" ?*

That one is regular and was used in the past. Some rare occurrences can even be found as late as the eighteenth century but would no more be understood nowadays.

[image]

That reads:

> Le trente octobre mille sept cents soixante quatre décéda Jean de Hauret tisseran de la marque de Candaloup **agé d'environ trois vingts dix ans**. Son corps a été ensevely le trente du dict mois dans le cimetière de...

Source: [Geneanet](https://www.geneanet.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=500798#p899519)

Note that a similar construction used to exist in English too:

> *John Horsfall was indebted in the sum of **three scores and fifteen pounds** to one Christopher Mitchell late of Chastleton. (1577)*, The YorkShire County Magazine, 1891

See also:

- [D'où viennent soixante-dix et quatre-vingts (plutôt que septante et huitante) ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/989)
- [Quelles parties du monde francophone continuent à utiliser les nombres réformés pour dénombrer au-delà de 69?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/187)

Comment: Il reste un réminiscence du système vicésimal dans l'hôpital des 15-20...

Comment: @None Oui, l'[hôpital des 300](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B4pital_des_Quinze-Vingts) !

Answer (score 0):

1/ It is never used, that is the first time I hear about this idea.

2/ You can't do that, not at all: people will not even guess what you are saying. If you are speaking with Belgian people, then, as they sometimes use "octante"  instead of the usual "quatre-vingt", you might say "octante", but in France, only a very well educated person would guess right away that you mean "eighty".

3/ The reaction can be an immediate interruption of your sentence and a request for an explanation, or it might be nothing on the spot because the person you are talking to  is not yet quite sure whether something is amiss or not, and is thinking that it is better to let sink in what you are saying. This is typical of all verbal exchanges in which improper terms are used.

4/ This form is foreign to the way of formulating the first numbers in French, just as the other forms you are talking about.

Note ajoutée à la suite de commentaires

([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discussion:80_(nombre))) Si, « octante » est employé parfois en Belgique aux côtés de « quatre-vingts ». En revanche, huitante est inemployé hors de Suisse.

([Académie](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/QDL078))  Il est à noter pourtant que les mots septante, octante, nonante figurent dans toutes les éditions du Dictionnaire de l’Académie française. Encore conseillés par les Instructions officielles de 1945 pour faciliter l’apprentissage du calcul, ils restent connus dans l’usage parlé de nombreuses régions de l’Est et du Midi de la France, ainsi qu’en Acadie. Ils sont officiels en Belgique et en Suisse (sauf, cependant, octante, qui a été supplanté par quatre-vingts et huitante — en Suisse — tant dans l’usage courant que dans l’enseignement ou les textes administratifs). Rien n’interdit de les employer, mais par rapport à l’usage courant en France, ils sont perçus comme régionaux ou vieillis.

Comment: I think that is not a bad answer but was downvoted by someone for whatever reason.

Comment: The Belgian statement is wrong. Belgians always use *quatre-vingt* like French. There might be a confusion with some *Suisse romande* people, but it's still incorrect because the word is *huitante*, not *octante*.

Comment: This answer is still based on the *octante* popularity urban legend.  See https://francaisdenosregions.com/2017/03/26/comment-dit-on-80-en-belgique-et-en-suisse/

Comment: @jlliagre That is merely saying that  "octante" is not the term used  by an overwhelming majority of the population, or possibly all of  it, this term being "quatre-vingt" nowadays; it doesn't say that it is not used sometimes; all I say is that it is used sometimes.

Comment: It is not used "sometimes", it is **never** used.  That's a urban legend. The quote you picked in a Wikipedia discussion is truncated, the statement that follows it reports it was used by a native French who wrongly thought he was speaking "Belgian".

Comment: @jlliagre What do you make of the article from the Académie? It has been supplanted; doesn't that mean that there are remnants of usage?

Comment: It hasn't been supplanted because it wasn't used in Belgium in the first place. Current Belgium is part of the *Langue d'oil* area where *quatre-vingt* coexisted with *huitante* and variants since the middle age while the specific form *octante* was merely a scholarly term promoted later in mathematics but that never took off. The *Atlas linguistique de la France* (end of 19th century) reports 22 "quatre-vingt", one "utante" and zero "octante" in Belgium.

Comment: An *agrégé de mathématiques* has been fooled by this urban legend: https://blogs.futura-sciences.com/lehning/2020/02/18/les-vestiges-de-la-base-vingt/

Comment: @jlliagre The article from the Académie says « … sauf cependant, « octante », qui a été supplanté par « quatre-vingt » »; il a donc bien existé en tant qu'usage dominant.

Comment: We are talking about usage, not literature. Better to trust real linguists like [Mathieu Avanzi](https://francaisdenosregions.com/2017/03/26/comment-dit-on-80-en-belgique-et-en-suisse/) than *Académiciens*.

Comment: LBU14 §590 est aussi intéressant : « _Septante_ et _nonante_ sont officiels en Belgique
et en Suisse ; _huitante_ en Suisse seulement (sauf à Genève), où l'on
employait aussi _octante_, aujourd'hui disparu (cf. Thibault, p. 451). ». On ajoute plus loin que le seul endroit où ce serait usité c'est en Acadie (Canada ; ou que Wartburg relève ça dans des dialectes) mais il y a des détails dont la lecture vous intéressera surement. DHLF dit de cette réfection latinisante de l'ancien français que « octante « est bien mort » (Thérive) ; son synonyme vivant (en Suisse) est huitante. » (DHLF/Rey).